# Python3 Selenium on Ubuntu script works when visible fails when headless

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image]I have a python3 selenium script on Ubuntu running in chrome successfully when I attempt to run headless it errors out on element not being interactable:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 143, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_MyReportViewer_ctl04_ctl00"]').click()                  
  File "/home/jobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click                      
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/jobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute                      
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/jobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute                      
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/jobs/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response                      
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable                      
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.88
```

I'd seen a post on that it might be how chrome interacts with objects differently so I've tried this with Firefox as well with the same results.

The only line I'm changing is:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

...implies that the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) wasn't interactable when you invoked click on it.

The element seems to be a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_MainContent_MyReportViewer_ctl04_ctl00"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_MyReportViewer_ctl04_ctl00"]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

In you are still unable to click on the element as an alternative you can use the *ActionChains* as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_MainContent_MyReportViewer_ctl04_ctl00")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_MyReportViewer_ctl04_ctl00"]")))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  ```

Comment: I tried with the WebDriverWait set to 20 and then 30 with no success. I took the screenshot during the running to see what was happening and I am thinking that Selenium maybe not see the full screen. That could be a red herring though. I've attached the screenshot above.

Comment: @StephenYorke Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.